# Reading and writing to same excel in optimised mode of openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, heroku, openpyxl

I am currently reading an excel file and keeping it in memory. I just need to read first row and then write large amount of data. I am using openpyxl but it's giving performance issues. How can I use optimized mode for both reading and writing?
Please find the implementation below:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=request_headers)   
xls_file = BytesIO(response._content)
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(xls_file)
data_sheet = workbook["Data Sheet"]
sheet_data = data_sheet.values  
columns_list = next(sheet_data)[0:]
//Query complete data from database and then creating dataframe by filtering 
//the columns in the data sheet
df = DataFrame(data=data, columns=all_columns).filter(columns_list)
for row_data in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    data_sheet.append(row_data)
// Getting the tables in the data sheet and applying that to the added rows and columns
for i, table in enumerate(data_sheet._tables):
    table_ref = i
    display_name = table.displayName
    reference_table = Table(displayName=display_name, ref=data_sheet.dimensions)
data_sheet._tables[table_ref] = reference_table
with NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    workbook.save(tmp.name)
    tmp.seek(0)
    stream = tmp.read()
    // calling api to and sending the stream.
```

Since the data can have more than 50000 records, i want to update the data sheet in optimized mode. I can not create a new workbook since i want to only touch Data sheet and keep all other sheets in the work book intact(these sheets can have charts or dashboards which would get updated based on new data)

Comment: Show some code, be more specific.

Comment: @CharlieClark added the code with proper comments and more details on my requirement. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also i tried to use write_only and that significantly reduced the time taken to create the excel file but i am losing the other sheets in the original workbook and thus it is not serving the purpose completely.